Playwright difference Browser Names ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] and browserName : 'chromium' with respect to viewport
What is the difference between the 2 types of setup in playwright.config.ts
file? When I configure the projects as :
      use: { 
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        launchOptions : {
          args : ["--start-maximized"],
        },
        headless : false,
        viewport : null,
      }, 

it throws this Error:
Error: browser.newContext: "deviceScaleFactor" option is not supported with null "viewport"

But if I configure as below, it executes without any Error:
      use: { 
        browserName : 'chromium',
        launchOptions : {
          args : ["--start-maximized"],
        },
        headless : false,
        viewport : null,
      }, 

What is the reason for that?

Did you look at what's in devices['Desktop Chrome']?!

What's confusing about the error exactly and what are you trying to achieve here?

It means precisely what the error message says:
browser.newContext: "deviceScaleFactor" option is not supported with null "viewport" 
If you open Chrome in deviceDescriptorsSource - you'll see that deviceScaleFactor == 1, which means it will try to change scale because of viewport, which is null for you.
That's why it doesn't work.
Try to use deviceScaleFactor: undefined instead
